# populating listbox with array generates parameter cannot be null error

Tags: arrays, vb.net, listbox

On button click, the array (named Input) which is pre-filled at this point is supposed to be added to the empty listbox. The code works and the calculation is actually shown in the listbox1.text, but I get an error that parameter cannot be null for item on the line: ListBox1.Items.AddRange(Input).

```
 Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles     
     btnDisplay.Click
    ListBox1.Items.AddRange(Input)
    Dim num As Integer
    For num = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1

        ListBox1.Text = ListBox1.Items.Item(num).ToString & ControlChars.NewLine
    Next num
```

Comment: What is the value of Input?

Comment: Input is a string array with 10 items, each item is an equation the user created. For example Input(0) = 1 + 1 = 2 or Input(1) = 6 / 3 = 2